# selecting folder using ranger file manager using bash hanging

Tags: linux, bash

I am using a file manager called ranger in i3. Basic task i am doing is "select a folder" for my daily workflow scripts. So i created a generic script,and using it across all my scripts.

my folder selection script shown below is saved under a file called folderselect. script shown below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TMP="$(mktemp)"
ranger --show-only-dir --choosedir="$TMP"
cat $TMP
rm  -f $TMP
```

when i include this script in other script like shown below.

selectedPath="$(folderselect)"

the script hangs and not executing anything. Please let me know what might be the reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ranger uses stdout to display its interface and $() redirects stdout to a variable, because of that you don't see the interface.

You need to redirect stdout to stderr to display interface:

```
ranger --show-only-dirs --choosedir="$TMP" 1>&2
```